# Как написать код элегантнее? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Как в Laravel средствами внутренних функций написать этот код более элегантнее?

```
$contents_list = Content::get();
$contents = [];
foreach($contents_list as $content)
{
    $contents[$content->slug] = $content->content;
}
```

Comment: убрать переменную `$contents = [];`

Answer (score 5):

Возможно, что-то вроде такого:

```
$contents = Content::lists('slug', 'content');
```

---

1. Советую не использовать
   [Snake_case](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case).
2. Называйте переменные через
   [CamelCase](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase).
3. Ознакомьтесь со стандартами [PSR](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/).

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
$contents = Content::pluck('content', 'slug')->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Если `Content` - это модель, то все просто:

```
// Получить все записи и задать ключи slug
$contentList = Content::all()->keyBy('slug');
// Получить записи по условию и  задать ключи коллекции slug
$contentList = Content::where(...)/*->orWhere() ... тут используешь доступные методы query builder'а*/->get()->keyBy('slug');
```

Answer (score -1):

В **PHP 7** foreach [не использует внутренний указатель массива](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php), т.е. работает с дубликатом.

```
$contents_list = Content::get();
foreach($contents_list as $content)
{
    $contents_list[$content->slug] = $content->content;
}
```